# can not reference "vkGetAccelerationStructureBuildSizesKHR" in building vulkan program

Tags: c++, linux, clang, vulkan, raytracing

[summary]
I can not compile vulkan program including "vkGetAccelerationStructureBuildSizesKHR" or "vkCreateAccelerationStructureKHR" with errors "undefined reference to `vkGetAccelerationStructureBuildSizesKHR'".

[environment]
OS : Ubuntu 20.04
command : clang++ with option -lvulkan
vulkan version : 1.2.170

[what tried]
I guess that it is need more library.
I added "-lvulkan_radeon", but it does not make any change.

For reference, If my program does not include any new feature of ray tracing, I can build it normally.
I read that ray tracing features are officially supported from version 1.2.167, so I expect that I can build it without any additional works, but I can't.
Is there any additional library to be linked?

Answer (score 0):

As with all functions provided by extensions and not being part of the core, you have to manually define and get the function pointers in your application before you can call it:

```cpp
PFN_vkGetAccelerationStructureBuildSizesKHR pfnGetAccelerationStructureBuildSizesKHR;
pfnGetAccelerationStructureBuildSizesKHR = reinterpret_cast<PFN_vkGetAccelerationStructureBuildSizesKHR>(vkGetDeviceProcAddr(device, "vkGetAccelerationStructureBuildSizesKHR"));
```

Comment: Thank you for advice so much.